# Article with "general truth"

Tags: articles

I don't understand what rule should we apply for the phrase.

On the one hand, there are many general truths, so we need to use **a** article.

> The fact that you're reading this is a general truth.

I googled the phrase and find out that almost all people use the phrase without an article.

> Can there be empirical evidence for general truth?

And, as far as I've understood, we should use **the** when we're talking about same general truth in two or more sentences.

Please, clarify when I should use an article with the phrase and which one for what situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Going from A something to a THE something**:

**A** general truth can be **a very simple idea** but difficult to follow.

For example, **a** watched pot never boils. **A** pot with water in it you are watching as it boils.

**The** pot [the one I mentioned above as a general proposition] does not boil is just a perception; the water or liquid in it will, in fact, boil at some point but will seem like a long time if you are watching it instead of doing something else while it getting to the boiling poin.

**No article is used with about abstract nouns**; an article would be used only if the abstract notion is in the form X of Y. **The beauty of this principle** is that it is simple.

**Truth** is difficult to understand even though philosophers have discussed it through the ages.

**Beauty** is a  hallmark of Renaissance painting.

**Rudeness** on the telephone can come back to haunt you.

**They achieved great **insight** into the problem.

You can **add adjectives** to the **abstract nouns** but they still do not take a or the.
The public statues in Ancient Greece were known for their **great beauty**.

But here **we have an exception**: **truth can be an abstract uncountable noun or it can be countable**.

For example: **"Truth is difficult to understand"** versus **A truth** about him is that he is very clever, in fact. [general] Also: In life, general truths [countable] are hard to accept.  BUT: **The truth of** the matter is that I don't like strawberries. [x of y, abstract noun].

**The fact that you're reading this is a general truth**. [countable noun, general statement]

**Can there be empirical evidence for general truth**? [abstract noun, no article].

**The general truth of the experience** was that I hated it. [abstract noun in the X of Y form].

Finally, **a truth** can be **the truth** if it is specific to a situation:
**The truth is one has to work really hard to sort out the use of articles versus no articles in English**.

The idea here is: there is a specific truth to the situation regarding use of articles versus no articles in English.