# Why is no article used before the nouns "custody" and "possession" in the phrase "to have custody/possession of"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

With most nouns, we use the definite article when we are talking about specificity. But why don't we use any article in such cases:

> 1. She has <s>the</s> custody of her daughter.
> 2. He has <s>the</s> possession of a gun.

In the above examples, we are talking about specific instances of those nouns, i.e., "**the** custody **of** her daughter', and "**the** possession **of** a gun"; then why don't we use any article here?

Note: With both countable and uncountable nouns, we generally use the phrase "**the/a** x **of** y", but with nouns like "possession', "custody" we have used "x of y", not "**the/a** x **of** y"; why is it so?

Comment: In cases like that, custody and possession function like proper nouns, like wealth or poverty. Possession of a gun in many countries is illegal.

Comment: @Lambie We do use an article before the noun "wealth": "a/the wealth of something", but not with "custody" and "possession".

Comment: No, "we" don't. **Wealth and poverty are serious subjects**. Do not confuse x of y with just x. Sometimes, with x of y, you need "the x of y" but not here. **Having wealth is a good thing**.

Comment: @Lambie, Ayden is not confusing _x_ of _y_ with just _x_, you are. The question is entirely about _x_ of _y_, and in that context _wealth_ does take an article ("a wealth of experience") but _custody_ and _possession_ don't.

Comment: @ColinFine in this question, custody and possession do not take articles, just like wealth and poverty. **In that sense**, they the same. Wealth as in The Wealth of Nations, is not the same as "Wealth is fine thing."  **No article**. Wealth in and of itself is not "x of y".

Comment: Does this answer help? https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/275891/61125

Comment: @EddieKal  That was a helpful answer. I understood most points in that answer, but I would be really, really grateful if you could do a "*He has **the** possession of a gun* vs *He has possession of a gun* vs *He has **a** possession of a gun*" comparison for a better understanding of your that answer. I would be very thankful if you could answer that.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/article-with-general-truth/158080#158080

Comment: I don't think this question is phrased in a way that helps learners understand the topic. An answer has not been chosen and a bounty has been awarded to an answer that doesn't directly answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

The rule with articles is that abstract nouns [don't take articles unless they are specified.](http://studyskills.curtin.edu.au/good-grammar/section-3-articles/relationship-with-nouns/#:%7E:text=Abstract%20nouns%20are%20often%20used,about%20a%20particular%20abstract%20idea.)

Here's how you know if it's an [abstract noun or not.](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/abstract-nouns.html)
It is possible for abstract nouns to be used with an article when they are specified (e.g. Risk scares people. The risk of being injured while playing sports can be reduced by using proper equipment and technique.). The problem with the two words that they are difficult to make specific.

Both possession and custody are, in fact, frequently used as can be seen on corpora (27k+, 13k+ on the [Web Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/) and 1.4k, 1k+, respectively, in [American Comtemporary English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).)

### Possession

Here are some examples from these corpora when they can be specific and used with an article. The examples show that possession can be used to specify both what is owned and who the owner is, but not the simple act of ownership.

1. The possession of a work permit does not exempt the holder from visa requirements.
2. Once purchased and in the possession of the buyer, it is the buyers responsibility for safe keeping of the tickets.
3. How did Henry Jr. come into the possession of a sword and dagger if he was a simple husbandman?
4. The land came into the possession of Spain by Right of Discovery made in the year 1492.

### Custody

Same goes for custody. There is similarly frequent use. Here are some examples from the corpora:

It seems to appear only when the custodian is specified such as a particular parent or agency.

1. In a letter to the Justice Department inspector general, the senator asked whether the current investigation also will cover the Bush-era supervision of the ATF in 2006 when, he said, " hundreds of weapons apparently moved beyond **the custody** and control of the ATF and possibly into Mexico and Arizona. "
2. ...if a student has recently been discharged or released from **the custody** of the Department of Youth Services (DYS) and is seeking admittance or re-admittance into the District...

I have to admit that it is difficult to make this perfectly clear, however, I hope that others can comment on other possibilities or anything that I missed which should be added (or removed).

Comment: I respect your answer, but this has not answered that why there is no article before those nouns which was the motive of asking this question. The examples you have provided are the ones which use the definite article with those nouns, but my question was about not using any article before those nouns in cases like "to have possession of", "they have custody of".

Comment: @AydenFerguson but by showing examples of when articles are used by default Yuri has shown you when they are not.

Comment: @mdewey but the entire question is that **why** no article is used before such nouns.

Comment: @AydenFerguson perhaps you need to clarify what you mean here by _why_. Are you searching for an answer based on the historical development of the use of abstract nouns in English?

Comment: @AydenFerguson I'm not quite sure what kind of explanation you're looking for. For the most part, I'd say that for someone learning these words (this is after all English Language Learning) would usually be enough. Since it appears not to be for your purposes, I must ask, why are you asking this question in the first place?

Comment: You have said nothing that differs from what I said. However, "Abstract nouns don't take articles unless they are specified." is incorrectly expressed. In fact, your wording make no logical sense.....

Comment: @Lambie I posted 5 days before you, so let's reverse reverse the You and I in your sentence, but let's also say that I provided sources and you didn't. What would be the "correct" expression in your opinion? Here's a source with a similar wording to mine: https://www.lingq.com/en/learn-english-online/courses/91431/137-articles-with-abstract-nouns-1129908/.

Answer (score 0):

**custody and possession are abstract nouns.**

*Abstract nouns do not require the determiner "the".*

- Custody of her daughter was hard to obtain from that judge.
- Possession of a weapon is a serious offence in some places.
- Custody of her mother was granted to her since her mother had dementia.

COMPARE:
**The custody of her daughters was granted** at a special hearing. [the here is specific, and qualifies a specific situation.]

- Custody is a complex legal issue.
- You can be arrested for possession. [of drugs, weapons, etc.]
- Possession is nine-tenths of the law.

COMPARE: **The possession of great wealth** is sometimes a terrible curse. [specific]

[list of abstract nouns+ not complete, of course.](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-abstract-nouns.html)

MORE ABOUT:
The x of y:

See my previous answer about that:

[x of y or the x of y and a/an x of y](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/article-with-general-truth/158080#158080)

Comment: Most abstract nouns are used with the determiner “the” (or even  “a”) when we are talking about a specific instance of an abstract noun: “I have **a** good knowledge **of** how these things work”.

Comment: @AydenFerguson Oh my goodness. I provide the basic answer and you provide a sentence that is really not **idiomatic**. **Good knowledge of a language** is needed in order to teach it. You must have missed the lesson on abstract nouns. Patience (I say to myself) is a virtue. "a good knowledge of how these things work"=red flag, non-native. *Knowledge of how these things work* is not easy to explain to those who shut off their powers of reasoning".

Comment: I have **a good idea of** how these things work. Countable: idea.

Comment: I may have provided a poor example, but I am pretty sure we would say “I have **a** good knowledge **of** English”.

Comment: @AydenFerguson And you'd be quick, certain and wrong in terms of standard grammar. I have extensive knowledge of biology but little knowledge of physics. So, you have the answer for possession and custody, and your first comment above is erroneous.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "Abstract nouns don't take determiners" or "don't take the determiner *the*" is one of those things that learners hear that is just wrong that then lead them to post further puzzled questions here.  *The study of science, the thought that I had upon waking, the desire to be better*, etc. etc.

Comment: @stangdon One thing is x of y and another is taking a determiner. I am not responsible for the complexity of English. study and thought are countable nouns: studies and thoughts. The ONLY explanation for custody and possession **not taking the** is **because they are abstract nouns**. Or do you know another??? There is no other explanation. And I have given plenty of examples that show they do not "take a determiner". Not every x of y is a "the x of y", that's the point.

Comment: @Lambie But you generalized the idea by saying "Abstract nouns do not require the determiner *the*'' which suggests that all abstract nouns do not require the determiner "the", which is completely a false statement.

Comment: @AydenFerguson NO, ***in and of themselves***, abstract nouns do not require a the determiner, which **explains** why so many non-native speakers have a hard time understanding how **they work**. And why this **does require one**: *The truth of the pudding* is in the eating. There are general principles at work, otherwise, one would not be able to systematize something which in fact can be systematized.

Comment: @Lambie I can provide an example where an abstract noun does require an article in the phrase you have mentioned: "I have **a**  better understanding **of** the condition".

Comment: @AydenFerguson The article **a** was not part of this discussion. But you can click on my answer for "a/an x of y" and "the x of y" in my answer above.

Comment: The article "a" is a determiner as much as the article "the" is.

Comment: The article a was not part of the question. There are many determiners in English. Want to go through every one? Stop being argumentative in ways that do not address the issue.

Comment: Let's talk about the article *the* then, "reputation" is an abstract noun, and it's grammatically correct to say "She has **the** reputation **of** being a good doctor". If you could solve this one, I would appreciate that.

Comment: That is another structure altogether: it is not: an/a x of y OR the x of y. That is: noun plus a preposition plus gerund phrase: being a good doctor. Being a good doctor is not easy.

Comment: Since "to possess" means "to have...", doesn't "to have possession" sounds somewhat tautological?

Comment: I'm afraid that Ayden is right to insist with respect to the two words he posted. The rule is that when any noun, including abstract nouns, is used with specificity it takes the article the. (That's part of the answer to **the reputation of being a good doctor**). The two original nouns are breaking this rule, though only about 1/3 of the time. I'm not sure, Ayden, if you're trying to understand specifically why they do break the rule when they do. There may be no answer, but if there is, it will probably be contextual rather than purely grammatical. There is no simple answer.

Comment: @Yuri.teacher.English I feel for you, I really do. "Many doctors have good reputations. **The reputation of being a good doctor** is hard to maintain." You can almost always **encase**  an abstract noun  in: the X of Y, and a/an X of Y. Abstract nouns and surrounding them with a structure are **two different things**. Reputation is an important concept.

Comment: @VictorB. Not at all  when the word possession is used legally. "She did not have possession of the gun/a gun" at the scene of the crime.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up in reliable collocation dictionaries, you'll find out that in collocations with the verbs, the noun "custody" is used without the article.

"Why?" you ask.

Because in that way it sounds correct to people who have spoken English all their lives.

*With* the article "the",  "custody" is used when followed by the possessive preposition "of", as in the examples provided by @Yuri teacher  English.

Please, see the collocations with "custody" here [(cambridge.org)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/custody) , here [(freecollocations.com](https://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=custody), and here [(ldoceonline.com/)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/custody).

As for "possession of something", it's, too, used without the article in collocations with such verbs as get, gain, take, obtain, acquire, lose, and others, as well as in set phrases "(be) in (full) possession of" and "have something in one's possession".

So, like you don't question the definitions provided in dictionaries, you just have to put up with the way the native English speakers collocate words, custody and possession included:)

Comment: [It, too, is used.]. Anyway, the reason you see them without articles is because they are abstract nouns.

Comment: @Lambie Who said they are not? Even if there are times when we do use articles--when we are talking about a particular abstract idea--when we're using them in a general way (misery loves company), yes, no articles are used.

Comment: You said it's because English speakers have spoken like that all their lives, when in fact, there is a reason, which I gave in my answer. Me voy, estoy hartíssima del tema.

Comment: @Lambie: "And why do you suppose those dictionaries show them without an article? Because they are abstract nouns". Amen!:)

Comment: As with the OG's question, abstract nouns can be used with articles when they are specified. "The love I have for my cat..." The examples given are with specificity. So in fact, the usage of these nouns does not quite obey the rules.

Comment: @Yuri.teacher.English Whatever you say:) I'm not into gainsaying someone with the user name containing "teacher English" even if English is not their mother tongue. BTW, there's quite an entertaining test on your site--in need of a slight fine tuning, though, IMHO:)

Comment: Thanks for having a look Victor at the test and glad you found it entertaining. Not being a professional developer, hearing that it only needs slight fine-tuning I'd say is an accomplishment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this really answers your question, but I think it helps. There are two other verbs I can think of that are similar. They are "control" and "use".

For example "She has control of the entire estate" and "He has use of the car".

This makes me think that, since these are very similar verbs to "possess" in that they are very personal in their nature, that they must have come from a specific historical context in English. Also not sure how "custody" fits as a verb.

Comment: I agree, this must have something to do with the word itself. Even “custody” and “possession” have a very similar meaning. Other words which are synonymous to the word “possession” are used in the same way without any article before them such as: “ownership, charge, guardianship”.